# Is it possible for a user to send me their whole app-directory for analysis purposes?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, document

Is it possible for an non-beta user of my app to send me their whole app directory for analysis purposes?

I know the way via the Xcode Organizer to download the whole app directory. But is this also possible for a end user to save/export a package of the app including all document files and send me this package via email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application directory and its contents are not end-user accessible without the use of a third-party tool such as [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) or [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I am sure there are many cheaper ways to do this, but I find [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/) really handy for browsing the device and copying complete app folders.

Another approach I suppose - easier for the user but tougher for you -  is to implement file sharing so that the user can drag stuff from your app via iTunes. It depends on how much / what kind of data you need from the user how you would implement this.